# Ignore Document Builder, SAX Error

Tags: java, xml, sax

I am reading some 100 XML file and some files don't have an end tag so I am getting an error. I want java to ignore those errors and continue with the next file.
Here is my code:

```
   package javaapplication1;    
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.*;
    import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
    import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
    import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
    import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
    import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
    import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
    import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
    import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
    import org.w3c.dom.Document;
    import org.w3c.dom.Element;
    import org.w3c.dom.NamedNodeMap;
    import org.w3c.dom.Node;
    import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
    import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.*;
    import static java.lang.System.*;
    import org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;

    public class JavaApplication1 {


        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            try {

                System.out.println("PLEASE ENTER FOLDER NAME ");
                System.out.println("             ");
                DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
                BufferedReader bufferRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                String s = bufferRead.readLine();
                 File dir = new File(s);
                String[] children = dir.list();
                for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                    String absolutePath = dir + File.separator + children[i];
                    File dir1 = new File(absolutePath);
                       String filename2 = dir.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + children[i];
                        System.out.println(filename2);                 
                        Document document1 = documentBuilder.parse(filename2);
                        NodeList employees1 = document1.getElementsByTagName("connection");
                        for (int q1 = 0; q1 < employees1.getLength(); q1++) {
                            Node employee = employees1.item(q1);
                            // Node nValue = (Node) nlList.item(0);
                            if (employee == null) {
                                break;
                            } else {
                                NamedNodeMap attribute = employee.getAttributes();
                                Node nodeAttr = attribute.getNamedItem("server");
                                nodeAttr.setTextContent("Ma.com:1531");
                                Node nodeAttr1 = attribute.getNamedItem("service");
                                Node nodeAttr2 = attribute.getNamedItem("port");
                                nodeAttr1.setTextContent("TS6");
                                nodeAttr2.setTextContent("");
                                Node nodeAttr3 = attribute.getNamedItem("username");
                                nodeAttr3.setTextContent("I_USER");
                            }
                        }
                        TransformerFactory transformerFactory1 = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
                        Transformer transformer1 = transformerFactory1.newTransformer();
                        DOMSource domSource1 = new DOMSource(document1);
                        StreamResult streamResult1 = new StreamResult(new File(filename2));
                        transformer1.transform(domSource1, streamResult1);
                    }
                             }
            catch (Exception sae1) 
    {
                sae1.printStackTrace();
            }
                           //}
            }


    }
```

Comment: please format your code and ask a question.

Comment: The Java XML parser is too strict and often flags things you can work around. You may want to look at some libraries that cleanup XML first before you run them through the parser or code a few fixups of the XML yourself. At the least you could put a try/catch block to avoid blocking on the first bad file.

Comment: In which way do you want your program to ignore the lack-of-closing-document error? Just to parse it successfully as if it was actually closed, or just give up parsing and continue with the next file?